# Cannot get the text of nth span element using vba

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have the following html part

```
<div class="description">
<span>Brand:</span> 
<a href="http://www.bestfamily.gr">Nikon</a><br/>
<span>Product Code:</span> 130342 <br/>
<span>Barcode</span> 18208948581 <br/>
<span>Availability:</span>Available</div>
```

I am trying to get the last span and the word Available using the following

```
Set availability = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName(".description").getElementsByTagName("span")(2)
wks.Cells(i, "D").Value = availability.innerText
```

But it shows all span texts
What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with HTML and VBA. Maybe consider this question for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42741997/get-all-innertext-vba

Comment: Try changing `ie.Document.getElementsByClassName(".description")..` to `ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("description")..`. Remove **`.`** from infront of **`description`**

Comment: It is not working it shows nothing in cell

Comment: Try using an elements collection and then use it's properties for the count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) css pseudo class in [descendant combination](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) with parent element [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors).

```
.description span:last-child
```

> The :last-child CSS pseudo-class represents the last element among a
>   group of sibling elements.

**Applying:**

single match

```
Set availability = ie.document.querySelector(".description span:last-child")
Cells(1,1) = availability.innerText
```

all matches

```
Set availability = ie.document.querySelectorAll(".description span:last-child")
Cells(1,1) = availability.item(0).innerText
```

---

Otherwise, you can return the span collection from that parent class and index into it

```
Set availability = ie.document.querySelectorAll(".description span")
Cells(1,1) = availability.item(2).innerText '<==choose your index here
```

Or even chain:

```
Set availability = ie.document.querySelector(".description span + span + span")  '<==expand as required. This uses [adjacent sibling combinator][4].
```

Sadly, pseudo classes [nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) / [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) are not supported in VBA implementation though you can in many other languages e.g. python.

—-

If after just the Available you should be able to use .description as your selector to return all the text in the div. Then use Split on the  .innerText using Chr$(32) to split by and extract the UBound (I.e. the last element of the generated array)

```
Set availability = ie.document.querySelector(".description")
Dim arr() As String
arr = split( availability.innerText, ":")
Cells(1,1) = arr(UBound(arr))
```

Comment: Yes but I get only the word  Availability: inside span, not the text Available which belongs to div? I am not sure

Comment: @Nikos select the div by class name. Split the .innertext and take the ubound

Comment: you mean Set availability = ie.document.querySelectorAll(".description div") Cells(1,1) = availability.innertext.unbound ?

Comment: instead of chr$(32) I just put ":" and I got the last word thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

As Zac pointed out in the comments, you shouldn't use a period `.` with the `getElementsByClassName` method.

`ie.Document.getElementsByClassName` is returning a DispHTMLElementCollection of elements.  You need to specify which element you want to reference

> Set availability = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName(".description")(0).getElementsByTagName("span")(2)

A better way to write the write the code would be to reference the Microsoft HTML Object Library and create a variable to test each element returned.  Unfortunately, there is a bug in the `DispHTMLElementCollection` implementation, so you will need to use Object instead of `DispHTMLElementCollection`.

> ```
> Dim doc As HTMLDocument
> Dim availability As Object
> Set doc = ie.Document
> Set availability = doc.getElementsByClassName("description")
>
> Dim div As HTMLDivElement
> Dim span As HTMLSpanElement
> Dim spans As Object
>
> For Each div In availability
>     Set spans = div.getElementsByTagName("span")
>     For Each span In spans
>         Debug.Print span.innerText
>     Next
> Next
> ```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Yes but I want not the titles above but the last word Available